# How to get value from PHP file Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I now have this `javascript/jquery` code:
I can get the value from my php file but i can only show it in a alert box.
I like to have this value (result) set into "texts" so it will show in my popup.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'; // jquery
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
window.onload = addElement;


function addElement() {
    // create a new div element 
    // and give it popup content 
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var texts;
    

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"index.php",
                    
                    success:function(result){
                       texts = result;   // does not work
                    }
                });             
            });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    
    newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup" style=" position: fixed;top: 15%;width: 800px;height: 200px;margin: auto;z-index: 99999;display: block;left:25%;background-color: #fff;  border: 1px solid #ddd;  border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 4px #000;  overflow: hidden;   padding: 10px;"><div class="popup_body" style="  height: 160px;">' + texts + '</div><button style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  style="padding: 10px;" class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';

    // Add The Background cover
    var BG = document.createElement("div");
    BG.style.width = '100%';
    BG.style.height = '100%';
    BG.style.background = 'black';
    BG.style.position = 'fixed';
    BG.style.top = '0';
    BG.style.left = '0';
    BG.style.opacity = '0.7';
    BG.style.zIndex = '99900';
    BG.style.display = 'none';
    BG.setAttribute("id", "bgcover");
  
    // add the newly created elements and its content into the DOM 
    document.body.appendChild(BG);
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, BG);
    // open popup onload
    
    
    openPopup();
}

function openPopup() {
    var el = document.getElementById('popup');
    var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
    el.style.display = 'block';
    BG.style.display = 'block';
    
    
}

function tostoring() {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Sms%20management%20systeem/testing/storing.php';
}

function closePopup() {
    var el = document.getElementById('popup');
    var BG = document.getElementById('bgcover');
    el.style.display = 'none';
    BG.style.display = 'none';
}
```

`results` got 'xxxx' as value. 
I got 'xxxx' into a alert box already, but i need to assign it to `var texts` in javascript.
I don't know how to do this.
Anyone know how to do this?

Index.php got:

```
<?php
    $var = "xxxx";
    echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

Help me please!

Comment: The variable `texts` is not defined inside that function. And even if it were you could no expect that changing the value of a local variable inside the function scope somehow changes the value of a function outside. That would lead to horrible issues, no code would work any more, since you'd have such collisions all around. You need to read about visibility scopes in programming languages. You could use a global variable or a property bound to some global object. Or you could call a function accepting that value.

Comment: It probably works, but the ajax call has not yet finished when you try to access the variable. You should move the code after the ajax call to inside the success function.

Comment: Wow it worked so far @jeroen Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, but the ajax call is asynchronous so javascript will make the call and move on to the next line. And when you try to use the variable in your pop-up box, the call has not yet finished and your variable will be empty.

You should move the code after the ajax call to inside the success function as only there you know for sure that the ajax call has finished successfully.

You also don't need the document(ready) block as you are calling your function on `window.onload` so the DOM will already be ready.

You should / could also move the css to an external css file as that will be a lot easier to maintain and share.

```
function addElement() {
    // create a new div element 
    // and give it popup content 
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var texts;

    $(document).ready(function() {
           $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",

                success:function(result){
                    texts = result;   // does not work

                    newDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="popup"><div class="popup_body">' + texts + '</div><button class="close_button"onClick="closePopup()">Sluiten</button><button  class="close_button"onClick="tostoring()">Meer Informatie</button></div>';

                    // Move all the css to an external css file

                    // add the newly created elements and its content into the DOM 
                    document.body.appendChild(BG);
                    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, BG);
                    // open popup onload
                    openPopup();
                    }
           });             
     });
}
```

Comment: I need to have the css inside my js file because our website is going to include this script only and it has to work. Your solution works Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you are econding the result in index.php file using `json_encode`, you have to decode the result in response as below:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"index.php",
  success:function(result){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
    console.log(obj);
  }
});
```